# SQL Join between timestamps

Tags: sql-server, join, timestamp

I have two tables like these:

**Table1**

| Timestamp | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-07-04 16:16:50 | 120 |
| 2022-07-04 16:17:25 | 110 |
| 2022-07-04 16:17:35 | 105 |
| 2022-07-04 16:17:45 | 130 |

**Table2**

| Begin_Timestamp | End_Timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-07-04 16:14:00 | 2022-07-04 16:17:02 |
| 2022-07-04 16:17:11 | 2022-07-04 16:17:30 |
| 2022-07-04 16:17:38 | 2022-07-04 16:17:47 |

I want to join the two tables based on their timestamp. So if the table1.timestamp is between table2.Begin_timestamp and table2.End_timestamp, it would add "isFound=1". For example, the first row of Table1 is 16:16:50 and is between 16:14:00 and 16:17:02 (the first row of Table2). I want a table like this:

**Wanted table**

| Timestamp | value | isFound |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-04 16:16:50 | 120 | 1 |
| 2022-07-04 16:17:25 | 110 | 1 |
| 2022-07-04 16:17:35 | 105 | 0 |
| 2022-07-04 16:17:45 | 130 | 1 |

I tried the following but it only works for the last row.

```sql
SELECT t1.timestamp, 
       t1.value,
       (CASE WHEN (t1.Timestamp BETWEEN t2.Begin_Timestamp AND t2.End_Timestamp)
             THEN '1'
        ELSE '0') AS isFound
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT * 
   FROM Table2
) AS t2
ON t1.Timestamp BETWEEN t2.Begin_Timestamp AND t2.End_Timestamp 
)
```

RESULT :

| Timestamp | value | isFound |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-04 16:16:50 | 120 | NULL |
| 2022-07-04 16:17:25 | 110 | NULL |
| 2022-07-04 16:17:35 | 105 | NULL |
| 2022-07-04 16:17:45 | 130 | 1 |

I use MS-SQL server. Can someone help me with that? I feel like this it is easy but I don't find the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a `LEFT JOIN` between the two tables on the conditions that the "*Table1.Timestamp*" is found between the two "*Table2*" timestamps.

Then you can exploit the non-matching rows having both "*Begin_Timestamp*" and "*End_Timestamp*" equal to NULL inside your `CASE` statement for the creation of the "*isFound*" field.

```
SELECT table1.*,
       CASE WHEN [Begin_Timestamp] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS isFound 
FROM      table1
LEFT JOIN table2
       ON table2.[Begin_Timestamp] < table1.[Timestamp] 
      AND table2.[End_Timestamp] > table1.[Timestamp]
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=abc6275d324f8381c648bd984ed3899f).

**Note**: this solution assumes that all your "*table2*" timestamp periods are disjoint among each other, otherwise you need to add the `DISTINCT` keyword right after the `SELECT` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *case* expression combined with an *exists* check:

```
select *,
    case when exists (
      select * from t2 
      where t1.Timestamp between t2.Begin_Timestamp and t2.End_Timestamp
    ) then 1 else 0 end IsFound
from t1;
```